# How to Reset Spyder Shortcut

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Windows 10 and I have my Spyder executable linked to my Start button.  I used to be able to click the Spyder icon and launch the executable and Spyder would start.  Now, for some strange reason, I have to launch Anaconda Prompt and type 'spyder' into the cmd window.  Then, and only then, I can launch Spyder.  Here is the path, from the Spyder properties.

If I right-click Spyder and click Properties, I can see the target is set to this:

```
C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\envs\spyder C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\envs\spyder\pythonw.exe C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\envs\spyder\Scripts\spyder-script.py
```

How can I reset this to work like it did before?  I'm guessing there is a way to do it through Anaconda, or maybe there is a setting somewhere on Spyder.  A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of playing around I got this to work.

1)    `Open the Anaconda Command Prompt (as administrator)`

2)    `Execute "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" mkmenus`